# Visual grouping of HTML elements by CSS background with rounded corners

Tags: html, background-color, css

I'm looking for a solution to group html elemts with a background. The real problems are the rounded corners highlighted in the picture. Is there a way to achieve this? 
[image: img]

Comment: Could you show your code that has everything but the radius?

Answer (score 1):

This solution still needs some work, but it's pretty close.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Ua6Ek/2/)**

Basically, I add a pseudo element before each list item using nth-child to group them with a particular color.

Also I set a lower z-index for each group.

I might be possible to play with the `clip` property to perfect this.

### Markup

```
<ul>
    <li></li><li></li><li class="last"></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li class="last"></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li class="last"></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
ul
{
    list-style:none;
    width: 350px;
}
li:before
{
    content: '';
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    height:70px;
    width: 80px;
    z-index:-1;
}

li:nth-child(-n+3):before
{
    background: brown;
    z-index: -2;
}

li:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+9):before
{
    background: green;
    z-index: -3;
}
li:nth-child(n+10):nth-child(-n+13):before
{
    background: pink;
    z-index: -4;
}
li
{
    width: 50px;height: 50px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.last:before
{
    z-index: -1!important;
    width: 70px;
}
.last + li:before
{
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}
/* clip the last item in each row */
li:nth-child(5n):before
{
    width: 70px;
}
```